# How to serialize/deserialize Java Object[] correctly?

Tags: java, json, serialization, protocol-buffers, rpc

I am writing an rpc framework, but facing a problem about serialization.

You know to translate Request between client and server, I should have a Request class like that:

```
class Request {
    // target service class
    private Class<?> targetService;
    // target service method
    private String targetMethod;
    // target method param types
    private Class<?>[] targetParamTypes;
    // the params
    private Object[] targetParams;
    // getters & setters & contructors
}
```

But:

1. for the `targetParams` field, if I use Gson as serialization tool, it will get `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to the.packages.to.MyClass` error if I put POJOs into `targetParams`, for the generic problem.
2. for `int` class, Gson always parse it as a `Double`, so I cannot use `targetParamTypes[i].cast(targetParams[i])` to force cast it to Integer(Double cannot be casted to Integer), it sucks...

So anybody have the solution to solve the problem? How to make the serialize/deserialize steps fast and accurate? Or any tools recommanded?

I have tried:

- Gson, get the problems before
- Kyro, the codec system sucks, I have no idea how to serialize/deserialize a HashMap...
- protostuff, ummmm, it not support Java 9+, my env is Java 11, SUCK!

So any advice?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as implementing the Serializable class?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial). Jackson's `ObjectMapper` should be able to convert from your `Request` object to `String` and vice versa.

Edit: added example

**Request entity:**

```
class Request {

    private Class<?> targetService;
    private String targetMethod;
    private Class<?>[] targetParamTypes;
    private Object[] targetParams;

    // needed by Jackson
    private Request(){

    }

    public Request(Class<?> targetService, 
                   String targetMethod, 
                   Class<?>[] targetParamTypes, 
                   Object[] targetParams) {
        this.targetService = targetService;
        this.targetMethod = targetMethod;
        this.targetParamTypes = targetParamTypes;
        this.targetParams = targetParams;
    }

    // getters and setters, needed by Jackson

}
```

**Serialization / deserialization example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Request req = new Request(String.class, "test", new Class[] {String.class}, new Object[] {"Test"});
    String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(req);
    System.out.println(serialized);

    req = mapper.readValue(serialized, Request.class);
    System.out.println(req);
}
```

Comment: No not work, get error when I use Serializable[]: `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.io.Serializable`... BTW, can you share a piece of example code to serialize/deserialize the Request class?

Comment: @UkonnRa Added example. Don't refactor to `Serializable` for the `targetParams`, but make sure the objects you store there are indeed serializable.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thx a lot! But why Gson doesn.t work using the similiar code(using toJson, fromJson)...

Comment: Welcome. Even though the method signatures are somehow similar, the Gson API uses a different implementation to serialize/deserialize objects. I haven't used Gson, so I don't know specifically why it fails.

Comment: No, it failed... I found that the type is error: `var obj = new RequestWrapper(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), System.currentTimeMillis(), HelloWorldService.class, "getExp", new Class[]{MessageRequest.class}, new Object[]{new MessageRequest(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 2, 10)});` And when you serialize it and deserialize it back, the `newObj.getParams()[0]` will be a `java.util.LinkedHashMap` rather than a `MessageRequest`

Answer (score 0):

use JSON instead of GSON and implement Serializable in your pojo